# Error 405 when trying to send an email from a static page

Tags: php, email, static, http-status-code-405

I have a static site up (my portfolio site), with a form to send an email to me using a custom php.

the page is through github pages and the custom domain is through google.

the form is:

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.8s" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                                    <form id="contactForm" class="single-form quate-form wow fadeInUp" data-toggle="validator">
                                        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <input name="name" class="contact-name form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
                                            </div>
                
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <input name="name" class="contact-email form-control" id="L_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                                            </div>
                
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <input name="name" class="contact-subject form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                                            </div>
                
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <textarea class="contact-message" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            <!-- Subject Button -->
                                            <div class="btn-form col-sm-12">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-block" id="form-submit">Send Message</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
```

And the php to send it is:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
     
    $EmailTo = "@gmail.com"; 
    $Subject = "Portfolio CV/Resume";
     
    // prepare email body text
    
    $Body .= "Name: ";
    $Body .= $name;
    $Body .= "\n"; 
     
    $Body .= "Email: ";
    $Body .= $email;
    $Body .= "\n";
     
    $Body .= "Message: ";
    $Body .= $message;
    $Body .= "\n";
     
    
    // send email
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);
     
    // redirect to success page
    if ($success){
       echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "invalid";
    } 
?>
```

The actual error I get is:

```
POST https://codewithmarcus.com/process.php 405                        jquery.min.js:4
```

I removed my actual email address from the code but rest assured it is in there correctly,  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

405 http code means **Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource.**

And you won't be able to send email via Gmail through this script. To send email through Gmail, you need send it through SMPT server.  You can use [PHPmailer library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)for that.

Comment: I switched to phpmailer library, and used one of their own examples https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/simple_contact_form.phps  but I still get the 405 code. Is the 405 error because github pages doesn't allow post requests?